# Right justification not correct

Tags: bibtex, horizontal-alignment, hyphenation

I am writing my thesis and I have started noticing wrong right justification. I have corrected some of them by replacing dashes with `\hyp{}`. However, I still struggle with the example below (citation breaks alignment). Any suggestions?

LaTeX code:

```
An interactive method for segmenting full\hyp{}enhancing, ring\hyp{}enhancing and 
non\hyp{}enhancing tumors has been presented by Letteboer et al. 
\cite{Letteboer20041125}. They evaluated their approach with twenty clinical 
cases. Based on a manual tracing of an initial slice, morphological filter 
operations are applied to the MRI volume to divide the data in homogenous regions.
```

[image: Right justification is broken by the citation]

```
@article{Letteboer20041125,
title = "Segmentation of tumors in magnetic resonance brain images using an interactive multiscale watershed algorithm1 ",
journal = "Academic Radiology ",
volume = "11",
number = "10",
pages = "1125 - 1138",
year = "2004",
note = "",
issn = "1076-6332",
doi = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.acra.2004.05.020",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1076633204003484",
author = "Marloes M.J. Letteboer and Ole F. Olsen and Erik B. Dam and Peter W.A. Willems and Max A. Viergever and Wiro J. Niessen",
keywords = "Brain magnetic resonance imaging (MRI)",
keywords = "brain tumors",
keywords = "interactive segmentation",
keywords = "multiscale image segmentation",
keywords = "watershed algorithm "
}
```

Comment: There is no room to bring `and` up to the first line of the paragraph, and dropping the citation to the third line will leave the second under full. What do you want `TeX` to do?

Comment: Perhaps »[microtype](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype)« can help here.

Comment: So, there is no quick and elegant solution to this? That is a worthy information too, because I will not waste time trying to fix it. _Thanks_.

Comment: Why should using »[microtype](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype)« not be quick and elegant?

Comment: A minor reword would help here: `... has been presented in a paper by ...` (perhaps). True, wrapping before/after the citation yielded sub-optimal results in TeX's mind, so it stuck with the best of the worst.

Comment: I thought that microtype would not work with pdflatex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [Thorsten Donig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1063/thorsten-donig), microtype is the solution:

```
\usepackage{microtype} %http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype
```